# I can't start NPM in a terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

Whenever I run a command in the terminal to start NPM, I get the error below:

```
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\SB\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-10T09_55_32_164Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\SB\Desktop\react>
```

Comment: can you add your package.json file here. what is being executed with `npm start`. most likely you might not have defined a `start` script in your package.json

Comment: Does `npm run start` works? `npm [arg]` will run a npm command and `npm run [arg]` will run scripts you set up in package.json

Answer (score 0):

add a start command to the scripts object in your package. json file and open your shell or IDE in the root directory of your project before running the npm start command.

Answer (score -3):

You need to run `npm run start` or something similar depending on your `package` file.

Comment: You don't need npm run. See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start